# Error in `$<-.data.frame ..... replacement has X rows, data has Y

Tags: r, replace

as a part of a project, I was given a medical dataframe for analasys. As part of the analasys, I had to fix the variable called "Gender", due to an error created by reading the data:

```
datS$Gender <- ifelse(datS$Gender == "¦ֳ«ֳ","Male", ifelse(datS$Gender == "°ֳ·ֳ¡ֳ₪","Female", datS$Gender))
```

However, doing so, changed the values of the variable to:

```
 1    2    3 
4461 3373  479
```

While those numbers are correct, their lable isn't. I attempted to fix that using the replace function:

```
datS$Gender <- replace(datS$Gender, c("1","2", "3"), c("Male", "Female", "censored"))
```

However, doing so reasulted in thje following error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Gender2, value = c("3", "3", "3", "3",  : 
  replacement has 8316 rows, data has 8313
```

The correct number of observasions is 8313, and I don't know what had caused the error. Can you please shed some light over why does this error occure?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `dplyr` approach to replacing the strange values:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        FixedGender = dplyr::case_when(Gender == "¦ֳ«ֳ" ~ "Male",
                                       Gender == "°ֳ·ֳ¡ֳ₪" ~ "Female",
                                       TRUE ~ as.character(Gender))) %>%
    select(Gender, FixedGender) # This line is just to compare the two side-by-side
```

Comment: When I tried it, it gave me this error: Error: Internal error: Trace data is not square. Is it because the feature has 3 levels?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have columns of factor type. Try turning it to character and then try your `ifelse` code.

```
datS$Gender <- as.character(datS$Gender)
```

You can also have a look at `dplyr::recode` to recode the values since `replace` cannot change multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the `factor` columns to `character` with `type.convert`

```
dat <- type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE)
```